# Wrong architecture for Delay-Loaded Library

Tags: windows, dll, dllimport

On Windows my x64 library (foo.dll) has a delay-loaded dependency to another x64 library (foreignlibrary.dll) that has the same name as the 32-library (foreignlibrary.dll). Sure, they are in different directories. Normally numbers are used like msvcr110.dll or msvcr120.dll, but in this case its not.

My library cannot be loaded because (at least thats what dependency walker tells me) because it loaded the 32-bit version of foreignlibrary.dll.

It seems its the first one it found with this name. How can I ensure the correct x64 library is loaded.

Comment: What on Earth would be the point of deploying that x86 version at all?  It will never be useful.  Only ever deploy it with the x86 build of your foo.dll

Comment: I don't deploy the foreign (32-bit) library, it's already on the system like the 32-bit version of msvcr110.dll and I can't do anything about that.I am just say'in that this library seems to be loaded because the name matches, so additional checks seem not to be there.

Comment: Pretty unclear why it would find the wrong bitness of that DLL, Windows has very specific countermeasures for that.  32-bit processes are redirected to c:\windows\syswow64 and c:\program files (x86) for example.  Anyhoo, put whatever DLL you have a dependency on in the same directory as the EXE.  That's where the operating system looks first, it can never go wrong that way.  It is up to you to copy the correct bitness of msvcr110.dll

Comment: By license I might not be allowed to ship/copy/modify the dll so I might be simply lost here. Thought this manifest-hell and lookup-procedure in windows is responsible to avoid these problems.

Comment: It all depends on how the third-party library is set up.  Have you asked the vendor how you're supposed to do this?  At any rate, you always have the fallback option of loading the library at runtime rather than using load-time or delay-loading.  (Off-topic but important warning, since you already mentioned licensing: some developers assert that you must have a license in order to develop code that dynamically links to their DLLs.  If you aren't sure whether the license in question give you permission to do this, you may want to consult a lawyer.)

Comment: I haven't asked the vendor yet. Was just wondering. Btw, it also happens that the wrong version is loaded. Do manifest files would help me here to ensure a DLL with a specific version is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in the Intel Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run your application that loads foo.dll, setup your environment to add the location of the 64-bit foreignlibrary.dll to the front of the PATH variable. When your application needs to load foreignlibrary.dll, it will find the one in the location you specify before it finds the one in the 32-bit directory.

You can either modify the system paths yourself or (what I prefer) make a .bat file that sets up the PATH and then runs your executable.

Assuming your .bat is in the same location as your exe and your library is in libs64:

```
@echo off
PATH=libs64;%PATH%
prog.exe
```

Comment: Modifying the path environment variable might work but I am wondering if embedding a manifest with the needed DLL might kill also the problem? Must the foreignlibrary.dll met any requirements so I can use it in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

This warning from dependency walker is not necessarily anything to worry about; Windows, unlike dependency walker, will ignore wrong-arch DLL files and continue searching for one of the correct architecture.  If there is no such file in the search path, *that* is when you have a problem.

And actually, for delay-loaded libraries, even that isn't necessarily a problem: often, these are delay-loaded precisely because they are optional.